# Get tab-key from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, tabs, key

i have a problem

I have an app that will help to create user's. And depending some conditions (checkboxes) i will save some information on localStorage.

My problem is when one person open more than one tab from my app, and the local storage overwrite the value that was saved on the first tab.

**Exist any form to identify the tab opened from my app (key value, identifier) with javascript, jquery, etc?** - Because i wanna use that TAB-ID to identify the values that i will save on my localStorage.

I need your help or suggestions...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get which tab the user is on, AFAIK.

You can use a form field with any meaningful value (like the client Id, if already available), or a random generated one, that will be used as an suffix for your localStorage key.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="foo" type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
```

**JS:**

```
var suffix = document.getElementById('foo').value;
localStorage.SetItem('client-foo' + suffix, 'bar')
```

Since it's an input, it will be submitted with the rest of your form. Obviously, you'll need to set the same value again across pages.